# Prisma connection string for local sql server

Tags: sql-server, typescript, windows, express, prisma

I'm trying to connect to a local SQL server from a Express JS app using Prisma using these URLs:

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=test;user=dummy;password=dummy;trustServerCertificate=true"
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://localhost:1433;initialCatalog=test;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
```

Both Windows Authentication and SQL auth is not working. The server is running in 1433.
But I was able to connect to a remote SQL server with user and pass. This issue happens only in local host.

Error:
Error creating database connection

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server logs to see f you can see the connection incoming? If yes, is there an authentication error?

Comment: `sqlserversqlserver` is definitely wrong. Which means you haven't tested Windows authentication yet. Have you tried connecting to the database using a client tool like SSMS, VS Code or Azure Data Studio? If you can't connect with them, you won't be able to connect from any application. Are you trying to connect to SQL Server Express or a named instance? The name has to be included in the source then, eg `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`. The port isn't necessary unless it was changed

Comment: @Larnu i havnt checked yet. Let me check logs. Btw I was working with MongoDB, iam new to this SQL server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, the Windows auth and user pass auth is working fine in SSMS. Also nvm the sqlserversqlserver, its a typo

Comment: `sqlserversqlserver` was my fault, @PanagiotisKanavos . The OP had some odd bold emphasis, rather than using code markdown, and looks like I copied the `sqlserver` part in twice.

Comment: Silly question, perhaps... if you can connect to a remote SQL Server but not one on localhost, have you installed an SQL Server on your localhost? If so, what version (2017/2019/etc) and what edition (Express LocalDB/Express/Developer/etc)? Is the TCP/IP protocol enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager > Server Protocols (for the given instance)? What TCP/IP port(s) have you enabled and configured it to listen on?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yep, installed SQL Server 2019. Working locally with SSMS via Windows Auth and user pass auth. TCP/IP enabled port - 1433.

But i didnt enable TCP/IP under SQL Server Network. I knew i was missing a minor config. Now its connecting via Prisma. 

Thanks ppl Larnu
PanagiotisKanavos
Always Learning

Answer (score 1):

From the suggestion from the comments, I found that I didn't enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER.